# Python - Is it possible to create fullscreen transparent windows on Raspberry Pi 3 (w PIXEL)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, transparent

I have been searching for a way to achieve transparent fullscreen windows on Raspberry Pi 3 (for overlaying content on top of OMXPlayer).

I have tried using wxPython, but exen with Xcompmgr and Composite extension enabled, I wasn't able to achieve this.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: hi @bogdanf, your question would stand a better chance to be answered on http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Might be worth trying PyQt.

Comment: https://wiki.wxpython.org/Transparent%20Frames

Comment: Tried both wxPython and PyQt. The problem is that on *nix system, you need to have the Composite extension loaded and have a compositing manager. This is the part i wasn't able to get solved